# How to encode subgraphs as hyperedges

Tags: graph-theory, coding-theory, hypergraph

Hi i was reading a paper "Propagating Distributions on a Hypergraph by Dual Information Regularization by Koji Tsuda", and one section stood out to me.

> hypergraphs have more flexibility
>   in describing prior knowledge, because known
>   clusters can be directly encoded as hyperedges. It
>   might be possible to convert a hypergraph to a conventional
>   graph, for example, by converting a hyperedge
>   to a complete subgraph.

My question is how exactly can one encode a small cluster into a hyperedge and how can one go in reverse. I've tried googling it but I've come up short.

Comment: It isn't deep. Just make a hyperedge that contains all the vertices of the cluster.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay The idea was to use this technique in a hypergraph that contains a series of words/concepts and their relations. then use a subgraph of these words/concepts and their relations as "prior knowledge" to generate a new hyperedge(or vertice). Based on your answer how would one encode the hyperedges belonging to the subgraph?

Comment: Here is one natural way to encode subgraphs as hyperedges, which is unlikely to be what the author meant, but worth knowing about. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a collection of subgraphs of a graph $G$ (e.g. the set of all copies of a fixed graph $H$). Make a hypergraph with $|E(G)|$ vertices, one for each edge of $G$, where the hyperedges are the edge sets of subgraphs in $\mathcal{H}$. Thus, certain problems involving the edges of $G$ can be encoded as a problem regarding the vertices of such a hypergraph.

Comment: For example, Turán problems for graphs correspond to finding large independent sets in a certain hypergraph.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that K.T.'s remark was ad hoc. While it is of course easily possible to create encodings, they will not be too natural or elegant. One can make some observations or may prove some small theorems that indeed the result cannot be truly satisfactory.